# Camel catch exception in Spring Boot layer

Tags: spring-boot, exception

I use Camel with Spring Boot and I want catch ConstraintViolationException:

```
public <E> E persist(E entity) {
        try {
            entityManager.persist(entity);
        } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
            entityManager.flush();
            entityManager.persist(entity);
        }

        return entity;
    }
```

but exception is not catched, I think the problem is with Camel which doesn't propagate exception to Spring Boot layer, camel route configuration:

```
private RouteDefinition processingRoute(String routeId, String inputEndpoint, KafkaEventNamePredicate predicate) {
    RouteDefinition processingDefinition = new RouteDefinition();
    String processingRouteId = dwhRoutes.processingRouteId(routeId);
    processingDefinition.routeId(processingRouteId)
        .from(inputEndpoint)
        .onCompletion()
            .to(PROCESSING_COMPLETE_LOG_URI)
        .end()
        .transacted()
            .to(KAFKA_MESSAGE_RECEIVED_LOG_URI, KAFKA_MESSAGE_RECEIVED_SPRING_URI)
            .process(kafkaMessageParser)
            .process(kafkaMessageFactory)
            .choice()
            .when(predicate).process(messageProcessor).to(KAFKA_MESSAGE_CONSUMED_LOG_URI, KAFKA_MESSAGE_CONSUMED_SPRING_URI)
            .otherwise().to(KAFKA_MESSAGE_DISCARDED_LOG_URI, KAFKA_MESSAGE_DISCARDED_SPRING_URI);
    log.info("Created processing route definition: id={}, from={}", processingRouteId, inputEndpoint);
    return processingDefinition;
}
```

Is it possible to propagate exception in Spring Boot layer with Camel?